# Autocomplete with Symfony2

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, symfony

I've an input text field and with a simple AJAX, my user insert 2 or 3 letters and get the occurence from my entity. How to add an entity in a input text field as an autocomplete with Symfony2 ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle) which has an interface to jQuery UI autocomplete. You can have a look at documentation here: https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/autocomplete/index.md

Comment: Be aware that although this bundle looks look and works OK - in the background its still making a query to the table and loading the entire table when the form view is loaded - for big tables it will be very slow